# Git rebasing branches

Tags: git, project-management, git-merge

I am managing a git repository and only have write access on the master branch. I have asked my colleague to create his own branch and push any changes to that branch and I will rebase them onto master. Now here's my scenarios:

My colleague checks out branch A and makes several commits. I continue working on master branch. Colleague pushes changes to the repository and I rebase them onto master. I keep working on master branch while my colleague keeps working on A.

Now, my question is whether colleague needs to delete A after the rebase and create a new branch or can he keep working on A? Does he need to merge the new master with A before continuing to work after the rebase?

```
A
| \
|  \
B   D
|   |
C   E
|  /|
H / F
|   |
I   G
```

**Edit in response to Tim's answer for formatting:**

This is not my scenario though. branchA never integrates changes from master. So basically:

```
master:      ... A -- B
branchA:    ... A -- C
```

and then:

```
master:      ... A -- B -- C'
branchA     ... A -- C
```

Note `branchA` remains unchanged. Is it now safe to continue working on `branchA`?

Comment: You seem very confused about what rebasing and merging are.  In your updated diagram, _no_ rebasing has taken place.  You should either strike _rebase_ from your question, or tell us what you are really doing here.

Comment: How do you figure no rebasing has taken place? I've rebased the commits from `branchA` onto `master`, creating `C'`?

Comment: That's not a rebase, it's either a merge or a cherry-pick.  And normally you would not be rebasing `master` on `branchA`, that's weird.  You would be rebasing `branchA` on `master` and then fast-forwarding `master` using `branchA`.  My answer does a decent job of explaining this.

Answer (score 1):

**Your colleague should be able to keep using the same branch** after you fast forward `master` with the changes from `branchA`.  The reason for this is that, immediately after your colleague finishes a rebase of `branchA` on `master` and fast forwards `master` with its own commits, these two branches should be *identical* at that point in time.  Note that this is sort of the opposite situation of what happens after synching up via a merge, in which case you would most likely want to delete the feature branch and branch out again with a new branch.

Consider the following simple workflow, which uses rebasing:

```
master:  ... A
branchA: ... A
```

Both `master` and `branchA` each get a commit:

```
master:  ... A -- B
branchA: ... A -- C
```

Now `branchA` rebases on `master`:

```
master:  ... A -- B
branchA: ... A -- B -- C'
```

Note that I have labelled the unique commit of `branchA` above with an apostrophe, because it is a *new* commit, which however would probably closely resemble the original commit `C`.

Now, we fast forward `master` with the changes from `branchA`.  We can do this because after the rebase `branchA` is *ahead* of `master`.  This leaves us with:

```
master:  ... A -- B -- C'
branchA: ... A -- B -- C'
```

And at this exact moment, both `featureA` and `master` are in lock step with each other.  We can rinse and repeat, because we are now essentially back where we started.

Comment: This is not my scenario though. branchA never integrates changes from master. So basically:

    master:      ... A -- B
    branchA:    ... A -- C

and then:

    master:      ... A -- B -- C'
    branchA     ... A -- C

Note `branchA` remains unchanged. Is it now safe to continue working on `branchA`?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, since his branch remains unchanged,  he can continue working on the branch. That said, since you are working on master, your respective codebases will diverge, likely causing more and more conflicts during rebasing. If you decide you want to start bringing changes from master into his branch, I recommend   scrapping his branch and making a new one instead of merging or rebasing master onto his branch.

My personal opinion is that you should be merging his branch into yours instead of rebasing. That way you can merge back and forth to always be up to date with one another. But I realize merge vs rebase is partly a matter of taste.